# Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Before posting I read the posts relating to the title and I'm sure there's a solution to my problem but I'm such a n00b with Extensions, JavaScript, and JQuery I can't tell...

The code that's causing the Refused is:

```
innerframe = $("<iframe/>").css({
    top: WIDGET_TITLE_HEIGHT + "px",
    left: "0px",
    width: "100%",
    height: "1000px",
    border: "none",
    align: "center",
    display: "block"})
.appendTo(innerdiv)
.load(function() {
    onStart()
})
.attr({
    frameBorder: 0,
    //scrolling:0,
    src: 'javascript:(function(){document.open();document.domain="' + document.domain + '";document.write(\' <!DOCTYPE html>' + '\');document.close();})();'
})[0];
```

The line src: 'javascript....' is the offender but I don't know what the solution is.

The posts I've read make it clear the code is violating Chrome's CSP and I've seen mention of message passing, sandboxing, etc.

I'm hoping someone can provide a solution and help me understand what's going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post the full error message.

Comment: Here's some info on CSP, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1):

Your script probably violates the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which says that scripts may only be executed on pages that come from the same domain. To be specific, they have to have the same protocol and host.

Your line `document.write(\' <!DOCTYPE html>' + '\');` is probably the culprit.